# How to write PHP Unit Test for Static Methods

Tags: phpunit

I am very new to PHP Unit Testing. I am trying to create Unit Test for the following function:

```
    $context = $args[0];

    if (Subscriber::instance()->isSubscriber()) {
        $context['body_class'] .= ' ' . $this->bodyClass;
    }

    return $context;
```

Which is very simple which adds classname in array if User is subscriber. Subscriber is class which has has a static instance method which returns true or false.

so far I have written this but I don't think this is correct:

```
$subscriber = $this->getMockBuilder(Subscriber::class)
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->setMethods(['isSubscriber'])
    ->getMock();

$subscriber->expects($this->once())
    ->method('isSubscriber')
    ->will($this->returnValue(true));

$this->assertInternalType('bool',$subscriber->isSubscriber());
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, You can mock PHP static methods using [PhpUnit](https://phpunit.de/) together with [Mockery](https://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/)!

Case: class to be tested Foo (`Foo.php`) uses the static method `mockMe` of the class `ToBeMocked`.

```
<?php

namespace Test;

use  Test\ToBeMocked;

class Foo {

    public static function bar(){
        return 1  + ToBeMocked::mockMe();        
    }
}
```

ToBeMocked class (`ToBeMocked.php`)

```
<?php

namespace Test;

class ToBeMocked {

    public static function mockMe(){
        return 2;                
    }
}
```

The PhpUnit test file (`FooTest.php`) with mock of static method (using Mockery):

```
<?php

namespace Test;

use Mockery;
use Mockery\Adapter\Phpunit\MockeryTestCase;

// IMPORTANT: extends MockeryTestCase, NOT EXTENDS TestCase
final class FooTest extends MockeryTestCase 
{
    protected $preserveGlobalState = FALSE; // Only use local info
    protected $runTestInSeparateProcess = TRUE; // Run isolated

    /**
     * Test without mock: returns 3
     */
    public function testDefault() 
    {

        $expected = 3;
        $this->assertEquals(
            $expected,
            Foo::bar()
        );
    }

     /**
     * Test with mock: returns 6
     */
    public function testWithMock()
    {
        // Creating the mock for a static method
        Mockery::mock(
        // don't forget to prefix it with "overload:"
        'overload:Geko\MVC\Models\Test\ToBeMocked',
        // Method name and the value that it will be return
        ['mockMe' => 5]
    );
        $expected = 6;
        $this->assertEquals(
            $expected,
            Foo::bar()
        );
    }
}
```

Running this test:

```
$ ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c testes/phpunit.xml --filter FooTest
PHPUnit 9.5.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 8.0.3
Configuration: testes/phpunit.xml

..                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 00:00.068, Memory: 10.00 MB

OK (2 tests, 3 assertions)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test (assert) static methods but you can't mock or stub them in PHPunit.

From the [documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.4/test-doubles.html?highlight=static):

> Please note that final, private, and static methods cannot be stubbed
>   or mocked. They are ignored by PHPUnit’s test double functionality and
>   retain their original behavior except for static methods that will be 
>   replaced by a method throwing a
>   `\PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\BadMethodCallException exception`.